# Using OpenMP how can I apply function across array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, function, fortran, openmp

using OpenMP with Fortran, I am trying to speed up the process of applying a function column-wise over an array. In the example code below, one 1 thread is getting used instead of all available 4. In the below example I am using a sum function (which is a simplification of the actual function that is much larger). What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers most welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
program prog2
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer                           :: i, j
integer, parameter                :: imax = 1000
integer, parameter                :: jmax = 1000
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: array ! input array
real, dimension(:), allocatable   :: res_array ! column-wise sums
real                              :: tempval
integer                           :: nthreads

! setting up array
allocate(array(1:imax, 1:jmax))
allocate(res_array(jmax))

do i = 1, imax
   do j = 1, jmax
      array(i, j) = (real(i+10*j))**0.1
   end do
end do


nthreads = OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS()
call OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(nthreads)

res_array = 0.0


!$OMP PARALLEL DO private(tmp, i) shared(j)
do j = 1, jmax, 1
   tmp = mysum(array(:, j))
   res_array(j) = tmp
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

contains

! dummy function summing up column
real function mysum(x)
implicit none
integer                             :: i
real, dimension(1:imax), intent(in) :: x
real :: tmp = 0.0
do i = 1, imax
   tmp = tmp + x(i)
end do
mysum = tmp
return
end function


end program
```

Comment: Don't know how to speed up what you're trying to do.  But, I do know that you **do not** want to do `real :: tmp = 0.0`.  It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: 1. The loop variable `j` must be private. 2. You can replace `   tmp = mysum(array(:, j)) ; res_array(j) = tmp` by `res_array(j) = mysum(array(:, j))`. 3. Same as evets: the line `real :: tmp = 0.0` creates an "implicit save" variable. You can read about it on SO or google it.